# VueJs App not updated on some devices on production

Tags: vue.js, caching, browser, deployment

I want my VueJs web app to be updated when a new release is deployed on firebase hosting.

First I was facing the issue because of serviceWorker. But as my app is not really a PWA, I deleted all things related to this (service workers, manifest.json, vue.config.js).

But I still have the issue on some browser, especially on mobile phone. For example :

My deployment generate these :

```
  dist/js/chunk-vendors.cd7afb70.js      359.91 KiB        127.55 KiB
  dist/js/app.4a639b92.js                205.22 KiB        51.00 KiB
  dist/css/app.2d238ab1.css              138.15 KiB        15.58 KiB
  dist/css/chunk-vendors.43f7171b.css    19.46 KiB         2.56 KiB
```

I check with inspector what I have on my browsers :

- On chrome desktop => files match ✔︎
- On firefox desktop => .js files not match ✗
- On safari desktop => .js files not match ✗
- On safari mobile => .js files not match ✗

After hard refresh / cache removing :

- On chrome desktop => files still match ✔︎
- On firefox desktop => files match ✔︎
- On safari desktop => files match ✔︎
- On safari mobile => .js files not match ✗ => can't remove cache

How can I force user's browser to get the last compiled files ?

Comment: It's a mistake to delete vue.config.js. Any way, this is specific to your hosting. The only thing that could affect this from Vue side besides SW is chunk hash, e.g. cd7afb70. If all chunks have hashes, they will be updated as long as index.html is updated. If this doesn't happen this means that web server forces index.html to be cached in browser. Web server needs to be configured to not cache index.html or cache it contitionally (ETag). It's also possible that some browser still uses SW.

Comment: As my chunk is well updated each time, this seems to not come from Vue. My problem is that even if I update index.html (in which I would like to delete the registered service workers), it will not be updated... I tryed to configure firebase.json as well but same problem, as the serviceWroking does not pull my code, I can't delete it.

Comment: But you said that you removed SW. Make sure there's no SW running in a browser, and after that this needs to be solved from hosting side.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the reply, I removed sw in source code yes, but it have been registered in users's browser. I don't know how to unregistered them.

Comment: This is a major problem with SW. If you botched SW, it needs an effort to fix it for yourself, and it's impossible to force a fix for users immediately. In Chrome, you can kill SW in devtools / Application. Can't say for safari. A reboot may help.